# Use environment variable in Spring beans.xml

Tags: spring, spring-4

I have a peculiar requirement of setting the value of some bean from system environment variable , is this thing possible in spring ?

Pseudo code

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="testhost" />
        <property name="username" value="$SystemEnv.RabbitUserName" />
        <property name="password" value="$SystemEnv.RabbitPassword" />
    </bean>
```

Now these RabbitUserName and RabbitPassword are externalized in some environmental variable which is outside .war file .

Is there any elegant way to achieve the same in spring ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and environment variables in .properties files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324702/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-environment-variables-in-properties-files)

Comment: Akshat, please select a correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

To get the System Environment Variable you can use this for the value:

```
#{ systemEnvironment['RabbitUserName'] }
```

The `#{ systemProperties['RabbitUserName'] }` mentioned in another answer won't give you a System Environment Variable, rather it will read a Java system property ie, those things you can set on the command line when starting the JVM, eg:

```
java -DRabbitUserName="reisen" etc...
```

However, this is probably a better choice of place for a connection credential than an environment variable, as, for example, you can then configure it differently for different launch configurations and it is also slightly less exposed than an environment value - which all the other applications also have full visibility on.

For more information on the difference between environent variables and system properties see [Java system properties and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables)

These are examples of the Spring Expression Language (SpEL), and you can also use it with annotation metadata, for example

```
@Value("#{ systemEnvironment['RabbitUserName'] }")
```

For more information on SpEL you can take a look at the Spring reference here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="testhost" />
        <property name="username" value="#{systemProperties['RabbitUserName']}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties['RabbitPassword']}" />
    </bean>
```