# Configure local variable in Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties

Before I start, I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965446/how-to-read-system-environment-variable-in-spring-applicationcontext) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324702/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-environment-variables-in-properties-files), and still could not figure out the issue.

I have a Spring application (you'll realise soon that my Spring knowledge is not very extensive) and four different environments (test, production...). Before, my properties file used in the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` was identical for all of them. But now I want to change it so every environment has slightly different properties. To do so, I have added an `environment` variable to the `value` so it grabs the right properties file in `servlet.xml`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
     <list>
        <value>classpath:circuitbreaker.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:${environment}.trackinganonymisation.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:runtime.properties</value>
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

My question is: where do I set the `environment` variable so I get it to be populated with the environment value?

Comment: Did you consider using [profiles](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)?

Comment: As a system property or environment property other values aren't going to be resolved at this point.

Comment: @Xokker profiles sound like a good alternative. It might be a solution, but I am not sure it's what I was looking for. It might be worth a try for the lack of a better solution.

Comment: @Tavo how do you want to set the `environment`? Why system property is not suitable for you?

Comment: @Xokker I need to set the environment via xml configuration. I have another project that does it programmatically using `@Autowired static Environment env;` and then `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setEnvironment(environment)` Not sure how that relates though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution was already in place and I didn't know. `${environment}` was set as a system property in the production machine to which I had no access. Even so, the solution was just to add that property to my local development environment.